# How to apply rotation to extrinsic and intrinsic camera parameters post-calibration?

Tags: computer-vision, camera-calibration

I currently have a set of intrinsic / extrinsic camera parameters, and am using them to project 3D world coordinates to the 2D image, using projection matrix $P = K[R | t]$.

My problem is that this projects them onto the horizontal image, however I want the image to be in portrait. I can easily just rotate the image after projection, but I want to manually rotate all the images to portrait beforehand and alter the projection matrix so that it can project directly to the portrait image.

I've tried the technique from [this post](https://answers.opencv.org/question/98187/how-do-i-address-rotation-when-using-calibration/), swapping the focal lengths and adjusting the principal point, however that did not seem to give the desired affect. Do I also need to apply a transformation to the extrinsic matrix?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I managed to figure it out. In addition to altering the intrinsic matrix, I also had to apply a 3D rotation around the z axis, in camera space. (since z is the forward pointing axis)

So I just altered the projection matrix to be:

$$
P = K' \cdot rot_z \cdot [R|t]
$$

where,

$$
rot_z = 
\begin{bmatrix}
cos(90°) & -sin(90°) & 0 \\
sin(90°) & cos(90°) & 0 \\
0 & 0 & 1
\end{bmatrix}
$$

and $K'$ is the 'portrait' version of the original 'horizontal' intrinsic matrix

$$
K' = 
\begin{bmatrix}
f_y & 0 & portrait\_width - c_y \\
0 & f_x & c_x \\
0 & 0 & 1
\end{bmatrix}
$$